# WPF Flip Card Animation

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, storyboard

I am developing a VideoPoker arcade game and a have a section on my xaml like this ...

```
<Grid>
        <Button
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Command="{Binding Card1Command}">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=Card1Image}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>

        <Button
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Command="{Binding Card2Command}">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=Card2Image}" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>

        <Button
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="2"                 
            Command="{Binding Card3Command}">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=Card3Image}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>

        <Button
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="3"                 
            Command="{Binding Card4Command}">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=Card4Image}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>

        <Button
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="4"                 
            Command="{Binding Card5Command}">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=Card5Image}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
</Grid>
```

All i want is a flip animation when i click a button on my view.
My viewmodel should start a storyboard ...

Do i need two Image controls one for back and another for front of my card ?

Believe me i spent many hours ... including trying Josh Smith's thriple ...
But i know that it should have something more simple ...

Comment: Try [this tutorial here](http://eren.ws/2013/10/31/creating-a-card-flip-effect-with-blend-boredom-challenge-day-27/)

Comment: UIElement.Projection Property is not supported Windows 7